# Reading JSON By JSON tag

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I got the data from a identity check company in the form of JSON. I just need to get some data from that JSON file so I deserialized JSON file and tried to read a particular tag. I am always getting null value when I am trying to read the tag . Below is my JSON file and C# code:

```
{
    "responseHeader": {
        "requestType": "PreciseIdOnly",
        "clientReferenceId": "21321",
        "expRequestId": "213213",
        "messageTime": "2020-05-28T00:00:02Z",
        "overallResponse": {
            "decision": "REFER",
            "decisionText": "Continue & Investigate",
            "decisionReasons": [
                "Continue & Investigate"
            ],
            "recommendedNextActions": [],
            "spareObjects": []
        },
        "responseCode": "R123",
        "responseType": "INFO",
        "responseMessage": "Workflow Complete.",
        "tenantID": "V123242"
    },
    "clientResponsePayload": {
        "orchestrationDecisions": [
            {
                "sequenceId": "1",
                "decisionSource": "PreciseId",
                "decision": "REFER",
                "decisionReasons": [
                    "Continue & Investigate"
                ],
                "score": 737,
                "decisionText": "Continue & Investigate",
                "nextAction": "Continue",
                "appReference": "22222",
                "decisionTime": "2020-05-28T18:58:43Z"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

Below is my code:

```
 var data = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(JSONResponse);
 string x = data["clientResponsePayload.orchestrationDecisions.sequenceId"].Value<string>();
```

JSONResponse is my JSON file from the company who is checking the identity. I get an error saying :

```
"Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: value
```

I am not sure what am I doing wrong. this JSON file is huge and have lot of nested JSON tags. This how I am Reading the JSON file send to me from the Identity check company:

```
HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(request).Result;
string responseContent = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
```

Comment: `orchestrationDecisions` is an array, not an object, perhaps that's the reason.

Comment: Per your suggestion, I tried to change my code like so: data["clientResponsePayload.orchestrationDecisions[0]"].Value<string>(). still getting the 'System.ArgumentNullException' error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of problems.

Firstly, `"clientResponsePayload.orchestrationDecisions.sequenceId"` is a [JSONPath query](https://goessner.net/articles/JsonPath/).  To query a `JObject` via a JSONPath query you need to use [`JToken.SelectToken()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonSelectTokenJsonPath.htm).  The [indexer](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/P_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JObject_Item_1.htm) you are using simply *Gets or sets the `JToken` with the specified property name* and does not perform deep queries of the JSON hierarchy.

Secondly, the `sequenceId` property is actually nested inside an array, so you need to use the path `"clientResponsePayload.orchestrationDecisions[0].sequenceId"` to get the first one.  Or, alternatively, you could use the path with the `*` wildcard `"clientResponsePayload.orchestrationDecisions[*].sequenceId"` along with [`JToken.SelectTokens()`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_JToken_SelectTokens.htm) to get all sequence ids.

Thus your code should be:

```cs
var x = data.SelectToken("clientResponsePayload.orchestrationDecisions[0].sequenceId")?.Value<string>();
```

Alternatively, rather than using a JSONPath query you could chain together indexers using the [null-conditional operator `?[]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-) like so:

```cs
var x = data["clientResponsePayload"]?["orchestrationDecisions"]?[0]?["sequenceId"]?.Value<string>();
```

Demo fiddle [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/6vlOOi).

Comment: Thank You. As soon s I changed the code, it worked right away.

Answer (score 1):

It's gonna be easier and more readable probably if you create a set of classes like this to get the value.

```
public class ReponseObject
{
    public Payload ClientResponsePayload { get; set; }
}

public class Payload
{
    public List<Decisions> OrchestrationDecisions { get; set; }
}

public class Decisions
{
    public string SequenceId { get; set; }
}
```

And then do something like this:

```
ReponseObject jsonObject = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ReponseObject>(json);
string sequenceId = jsonObject.ClientResponsePayload.OrchestrationDecisions.First().SequenceId;
```

Anyway, if you don't want to create the classes you could do it like this:

```
data["clientResponsePayload"]["orchestrationDecisions"][0]["sequenceId"].Value<string>()
```

Comment: MY JSON is not small. Very big file. I just posted a small part of tis JSON. I can create a object, but the value I am trying is nested inside lot of JSON tags.